# In which sense is quantum cohomology a deformation of cohomology?

Tags: symplectic-geometry, de-rham-cohomology

I've read, for instance [in](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9804145.pdf), that quantum cohomology is a deformation of singular cohomology, or that quantum de Rham cohomlogy is a deformation of de Rham cohomology. However, I've not found a definition of what this means technically. Is this just a "philosophical" deformation, in the sense that it is a "change", not a deformation of say algebras (as example of a "technical" usage of the term)? I've heard people use the word quantum in relation to $q$-deformation, but I don't know if this is related at all.

Comment: It looks to me as though this is very similar to the notion of the deformation of an algebra. This is very similar to how in deformation quantization, one extends an algebra from say $(A,\mu)$ to $(A^\nu, \mu')$ where $A^\nu$ is the set of formal power series in $\nu$ with coefficients in $A$  and $\mu'$ is a deformation of $\mu$. In quantum cohomology, you take $A$ to be the exterior algebra with $\mu=\wedge$ and then deform it in a similar way as before, while also defining a deformed exterior derivative compatible with the deformed wedge.